# Question about Gentry's "Computing Arbitrary Functions of Encrypted Data"

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I am working through the "Computing Arbitrary Functions of Encrypted Data" by Gentry, trying to understand more about Fully Homomorphic Encryption. I'm stuck trying to understand why his "Somewhat Homomorphic Scheme" presented in section 3 is correct.  Ignoring the homomorphic aspects of his scheme, I'm struggling just to prove that $\text{decrypt}(p, \text{encrypt}(p,m)) \stackrel{?}{=} m$.

Gentry defines $N = \lambda, P = \lambda^2, Q = \lambda^5$ and

$\operatorname{KeyGen}(\lambda)$: A random $P$-bit, odd integer

$\operatorname{Encrypt}(p,m)$: Let $m'$ be an $N$-bit number s.t. $m' \equiv m \pmod 2$. Output $c = m' + pq$, where $q$ is a random $Q$-bit number

$\operatorname{Decrypt}(p,c):$ Output $(c \mod p)\mod 2)$, where $(c \mod p)$ is the integer $c'$ in $(-p/2, p/2)$ s.t. $p$ divides $c - c'$

I think there's a counterexample when $p = 1$ (you can force this by setting $\lambda = 1$, because $(c\mod 1) = 0$. Thus, it seems that $p \in \{3,5,\ldots 2^{P}\}$.  I'm wondering if there are other restrictions on the domain of $p$, for example, if we knew that $p > m'$, it would be nearly trivial to show that decrypt works: $(c \mod p) \mod 2 = (m' + pq \mod p) \mod 2 = (m' \mod 2) = m$.

Comment: $\lambda$ is the security parameter. Setting it to 1, yes you have obviously had no security. It is like saying have a block cipher with $\lambda$ key size. Now set it 1!

Comment: This is a fair criticism of $\lambda =1$, but, for any $\lambda$, $1$ is a possible random $P$-bit odd integer, so the counter-example holds. Unless Gentry means $p \in [2^{P-1},  2^{P} -1]$ when he says $P$-bit integer.

Comment: The probability of sampling $p = 1$ is negligible.

Comment: $p$ has $\lambda^2$ bits, that is $p \in [2^{\lambda^2-1}, 2^{\lambda^2} - 1]\cap \mathbb{Z}$, therefore, $p > 2\cdot 2^\lambda > 2\cdot m'$, therefore, the decryption works even if you use the "centered" reduction modulo $p$.